# How do I stop SQLCMD from misinterpreting variable parameters?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have a server config script we call with SQLCMD that runs a lot of other scripts in a folder, using `:R \\folder\path\script.sql`.
One of those scripts creates an Agent job that has a TSQL step that uses parameterized variables, i.e. `'$(A-MSG)'` and SQLCMD treats these like variable expansion as it executes the script and throws errors that they're not defined (which they wouldn't be, until that Agent job executes).

We can make it execute and create the job correctly if we run the sub-script directly, using `sqlcmd -i \\folder\path\script.sql -x`. Is there a similar way to disable variable expansion when running a server config script that executes sub-scripts with `:R`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe someone can suggest a better method as this seems a kludge but instead of `:r`, you could shell out to another SQLCMD session:

```
::sqlcmd -i \\folder\path\script.sql -x -I
```

Also added `-I` for `QUOTED IDENTIFIERS ON` to override the horrible default of `OFF`.